# Troubles while using Android Studio in Mac

Tags: android, android-studio

I just started developing application for android. I found some troubles with using Android Studio in MAC. I have mentioned my points below:

1. When I drag and drop some controls from palette, it is automatically became relative to the the above controls in design view. How to make all controls to relative only one view? kind of absolute position to main view.
2. If relative layout is terms for position , I don't understand why changing position of one controls affect to the frame(height and width) of other relatives controls.
3. Is there any way to change default layout while creating new project.
4. Up/Down/Left/Right arrows of keyboard are helpless to move controls.

Really appreciate your help. It will boost up my android developing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/keyboard-shortcuts-you-cannot-miss.html

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-templates.html

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/navigation-in-source-code.html

Comment: Hey Yiati, thanks for your reply. For the relative layout I still don't understand how it is working in design view. I can not move my element. I checked Keymap in my preference but i can not find any keys to move element in design view. arrows keys are not working. I tried to change sort cut even but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You can use the Design view if you want to create layouts, however I won't be able to help you there. Although it's better than it has been in the past it is still very difficult to use, and I simply use the Text view and only create views in xml, as does everyone I know. I do believe that you will have a better understanding and control if you make your views in the xml Text view instead.

Comment: Yes may be I need to do practicing my layout design with coding. I used Xcode and Visual Studio, but layout design view experience of Android Studio, is hard to accept.